# Retrieving an object of a database shelve python

Tags: python, database, object

I save an object in a database in python but when I try to print it it just prints the location of the object. How can I print the actual data of the object?

Assuming the object is student with an id as "key" and email, address as the objects data

```
 def getrecord(self,Id):
            rec=self.db[Id]
            print(rec)
```

The output I get:

```
...object at 0x02605B10>
```

What I would like to see:

```
"student@gmail.com, central park, new york"
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Looks like the retrieval works fine, and the problem is that `rec` is something that has neither a `__str__` method, nor a `__repr__` method.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `rec` is a database record object.

What mechanism are you using to retrieve from the database?  An ORM like sqlalchemy?  Or directly via an interface such as MySQLdb?  The api of your library might explain the data better.

You might try something like `print rec.__dict__` to see if the values are part of the rec object, such that you could access the individual return parameters directly `print '{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(rec.email, rec.address, rec.city)`.

Also, depending on what environment you're working in, the console in pycharm, pydev/eclipse can give you some insight into the methods and fields on your record object.